# change text button after successful login in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I can't find answer/guide in google. How can I change the text of the login button
to "Logout" after the user successfully login. I'm working on ASP.NET MVC 5 web application. thanks for helpful answers/guides.

Comment: Are you using the inbuilt authentication comes with the default project template from VS ? Asp.Net Identity ?

Comment: No, I started working with empty MVC. because I wanted to learn from the scratch. My login form is working fine. I check the username and password in the database table

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I present a "Login" or "Logout" link to the user in my application, using [`Request.IsAuthenticated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if the user is logged in or not.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">
            Log Out
        </a>
    }
}
else
{
    <a id="loginlink" href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")">
        Login
    </a>
}
```

This of course requires an `Account` controller with `LogOff` and `Login` methods, but it gets the idea across.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I kinda understand the flow of your code but Im not really familiar with the Request.IsAuthenticated code and other syntax. I'm just getting the values of inputs then check it against the database. Can I use that built in code with my existing methods? Will there be no problem? thanks.

Comment: Since you're doing it from scratch, you likely don't have any [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) membership capabilities, so using `Request.IsAuthenticated` won't work. However, the idea is the same. At some point, your users will log in, and when they do, you could either set a flag or use session variables to track that they have successfully logged in. Then in your code, you can check that flag or session variable you set earlier and present different content based on its value.

Comment: Where did you write the code for Request.IsAuthenticated , is it in the Model class? thanks.

Comment: That's not mine, it's part of .NET, in System.Web. Check link in my answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (Session["Username"] !=null)
                          {
                                <a href="@Url.Action("LogOut", "Login")" class="cta-btn">LogOut</a>

                          }
                          else
                          {
                            <a href="/Signup/Signup" class="cta-btn ">Signup</a>    
                            <a href = "/Login/login" class="cta-btn">Login</a>
                          }
```